# Strategy to rename the require_once function?

Tags: php

Rather than just writing a new function called import() i'd like to know if there's a better solution. Otherwise require_once would be included in the scope of import() only, which is bad for any "global" variable there.

My import() function would work differently than require_once, but serves the same purpose (enhanced usability).

Comment: That's a new one. I've never heard of a usability problem with a library function that scared off developers simply by the name. While you're at it, consider removing strip*(), chop(), explode(), implode(), die(), and other pseudo-violent-sounding functions for good measure. Where does it end?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making things easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My gut instict opinion: Nah. Don't do it.

- A language has its native set of functions. Why introduce a proprietary function that has no added value.
- I don't think there is reason to be scared off by `require_once()`.
- I agree with you, using globals is not a great thing, but sacrificing the possibility of using them for a vanity function name is not a good way to go.

If paths are what you're worried about, then why not write an `import()` function that returns the correct path. Like so:

```
require_once import("operations.php");
```

the only - in my eyes not so horrible - downside is that you only have to make sure that import always returns a correct path to *something*, otherwise `require_once` will crash. Other than that, it has the same comfort, allows you to control paths as you wish, but doesn't cost you anything in terms of flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about you and your team but I've never met a PHP developer "scared off" by require/include - that's just the way the language works.

If you're scared off by such things perhaps you should be using another language.

And what you're proposing sounds like a maintainence nightmare.

Comment: you shouldn't take things too seriously ;) I said that it sucks to have to think about paths every time, so I just simplified it dramatically. Nothing wrong with making life easier, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly get something similar to what you're after by using `__autoload()`.  Then you could just use whatever class you want, without `require`ing it, and so long as its file is in your include_path it will be loaded without trouble.

(This of course assumes that the file you're trying to include has a class in it, and that the class and its file are named according to some convention.  Probably that's *not* actually the case.)

This is a pretty standard autoloader, that works with Zend- and Pear-style naming conventions:

```
<?php
/**
 * Load (include the file of) a given PHP class.
 *
 * @param string $class The name of the class to load.
 *
 * @return void
 */

function __autoload($class)
{
    $files = array(
        $class . '.php',
        str_replace('_', '/', $class) . '.php',
    );
    foreach (explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, ini_get('include_path')) as $base_path) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $path = "$base_path/$file";
            if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {
                include_once $path;
                $finalPath = $path;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isset($finalPath)) {
        return;
    } else {
        die("Unable to load class '$class'.");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could cut down on the number of `require` calls by creating an import function and attaching it to a class. So after requiring the framework once, users could then use the import function for including other framework classes. To wit:

index.php:

```
require_once 'MyFramework.php';
MyFramework::import('Path/To/File.php');
```

MyFramework.php

```
class MyFramework {
 static function import($path) {
   // code to include/import the path
 }   
}
```

Another option would be to use the PHP's auto_load semantics to automatically `require` framework classes:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Though at the end of the day you can't really replace the require/include statements, short of editing the PHP source.